# How to hide clipped views in SwiftUI HStack

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swiftui, swiftui-list

Is there a possibility in SwiftUI to show only as many (fixed size) views in one row as fit without clipping, e.g. cutting of parts of the view.

### Example Layout

```
 ----------------------------------------- 
|                                         |
|  -------     -------     -------     -------     -------
| | VIEW1 |   | VIEW2 |   | VIEW3 |   | VIEW4 |   | VIEW5 |
|  -------     -------     -------     -------     -------
|                                         |
 -----------------------------------------
```

In this example `VIEW5` should be hidden, because it is completely out of bounds with respect to the parent view.
This could be done with `.clipped()`.

`VIEW4` should also be **completely hidden**!
Because if it would be shown, it must be cut off.
All other views should be rendered normally.

### SwiftUI Layout

This initial try has the following problems:

- since the width of the `itemView` is much larger then the outer `VStack`, the leading edges are not aligned => ☑️ [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65308892/10026834)
- ❌The last view might be visible even if it is not fully on screen. This should be avoided.

```swift
struct DemoView: View {
    let items: [String]
    @State private var totalHeight = CGFloat.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Demo View:")
            itemView
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
    
    private var itemView: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .fixedSize()
                    .padding(.all, 5)
                    .font(.body)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 350)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct DemoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var items: [String] = (2000..<2020).map(String.init)
//        .map { item in
//            Bool.random() ? item : item + item
//        }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoView(items: items)
//            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
#endif
```

[image: Wrong Layout Example]

Comment: Your leading edge problem is because your HStack is aligned to .center by default. On your HStack, just add ... HStack(alignment: .leading).

Comment: That was fast tank you. But the major problem is, that I don‘t want that a clipped view is visible. Your solution fixes the alignment problem but there might be a view at the trailing edge that is not fully visible.

Comment: As a developer, it's usually preferable to allow the training items to get cut off, because that signals to the user that there are more items to the right if they want to scroll. However, if you want to clip it at the edge of the frame, just add. clipped()  after the .frame() modifier(like in to @Asperi's answer below).

Comment: In this case, I just want to show the Items that are fully visible. If I add clipped() this might not be the case because the last item might get cut off. This is exactly what I try to prevent. I will try to make it more clear in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Use clipped with alignment on `HStack` frame (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
private var itemView: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .fixedSize()
                .padding(.all, 5)
                .font(.body)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: 350, alignment: .leading)
    .clipped()
}
```

Comment: Thanks gor your answer, but it only fixes the first problem (alignment). And not the fact that there might be a view that is clipped (not fully visible). This last view should be hidden in case it is not fully on screen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on your comments. The VStack is aligned to leading, and then I added a ScrollView to hold the HStack of items. Further, I added a white .overlay to each item where the opacity will change from 1.0 (full covering the item) to 0.0 (showing the item) when the item moves fully onto screen.

Also note that I moved the leading padding to within the VStack, this way when you scroll to the left, the items move to the edge of the screen instead of getting cut off where the padding was.

```
struct DemoView: View {
    let items: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Demo View:")
                .padding(.leading)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .fixedSize()
                            .padding(.all, 5)
                            .font(.body)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .overlay(
                                GeometryReader { geometry in
                                    Color.white
                                        .opacity(
                                            geometry.frame(in: .global).maxX < UIScreen.main.bounds.width ? 0.0 : 1.0
                                        )
                                }
                            )
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.orange) // Starting HStack
                .padding(.leading)
                .background(Color.green) // Scrollable area
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct DemoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoView(items: [
            "ONE",
            "TWO",
            "THREE",
            "FOUR",
            "FIVE",
            "SIX",
            "SEVEN",
            "EIGHT",
            "NINE",
            "TEN",
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super cool! Thank you. :)
In my usecase there should not be a scrollview. I could add the `.disables(true)` modifier to the `ScrollView`. Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Happy to help. FYI, when you set .disable(true) it will disable all human interaction. So if you plan on making these buttons, they wouldn't be clickable. Otherwise, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer from [nicksamo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65328732/10026834) with generic content `ViewBuilder`. Thank you for this solution! :)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct NonClippingView<Item: Hashable, Content: View>: View {
    let items: [Item]
    let isScrollingDisabled: Bool
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let content: (Item) -> Content

    init(items: [Item], isScrollingDisabled: Bool = false, backgroundColor: Color = .white, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> Content) {
        self.items = items
        self.isScrollingDisabled = isScrollingDisabled
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        content(item)
                            .overlay(
                                GeometryReader { geometry in
                                    backgroundColor
                                        .opacity(
                                            geometry.frame(in: .global).maxX < proxy.size.width ? 0.0 : 1.0
                                        )
                                }
                            )
                    }
                }
//                .background(Color.orange) // Starting HStack
                .padding(.leading)
//                .background(Color.green) // Scrollable area
            }
            .disabled(isScrollingDisabled)
        }
    }
    
}

struct NonClippingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NonClippingView(items: [
            "ONE",
            "TWO",
            "THREE",
            "FOUR",
            "FIVE",
            "SIX",
            "SEVEN",
            "EIGHT",
            "NINE",
            "TEN",
        ], content: { item in
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "tag")
                Text(item)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            .padding(.all, 5)
            .font(.body)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(5)
        })
    }
}
```